# modifications in meta data depending on query string?

Tags: php, html, metadata

Is it possible to make modifications in the meta data of an HTML page using query string? like

```
page.php?metatitle=testtitle
```

meta data of page.php:

```
<meta name="title" content="<?php $_GET['metatitle'] ?>"/>
```

I've tried this but, it doesn't work :( Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your code properly change to this

```
<?php print $_GET['metatitle'] ?>
```